# Where to load Driver for PostgreSQL on JAX-RS 2 (Servlet 3) no web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

currently i'm trying to play with Servlet 3.0 and JAX-RS 2.0.
I tried to setup a PostgreSQL database but I don't know where to load the driver?

I only have a Application class and no web.xml Also I don't know where to put any initial code?!

Comment: Don't... Just add the postgresql driver to your clasaspath and it will be loaded automatically. People should really stop doing manual loads of JDBC drivers.

Comment: And still I would need some initialization code, like connecting to the database.

Comment: IN your java code use a `DriverManager` to get a connection based off the URL you provide. Or configure a datasource somewhere and use that to get a connection.

Comment: You need to configure a `DataSource` for your Servlet container. In Tomcat that would typically be done in the global `context.xml` located in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` See the manual for your Servlet container.